# How to change the diameter of a water stream?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, home-experiment, experimental-technique

So I am conducting experiments investigating the change of sound as a bucket fills up with water. One of the parameters which changes the sound heard is the diameter of the stream of water filling up the bucket. 
My trouble is finding a reliable way of changing the diameter of the water stream . All the nozzles available 'spray' water instead of giving a stream. Are nozzles not what I need ? If so then how do I solve this problem.

Comment: The water splits up due to turbulence in flow. For smooth, streamlined,ideal flow the water would not be sprayed. Try reducing the speed.

Comment: The problem is that all the nozzles that I can find are, in fact ,designed to spray.

Comment: Don't use nozzles. You can try with a tap, if you want.